# How to scroll the screen (i mean how to move the screen )

Tags: android

Here i have 10 field. i can view only 9 fields at a time and i con't scroll this screen...
so how to make this screen scrollable... friends just help me..

Here is my coding.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"


android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
<TableRow>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_waybilltype"
        android:layout_column="1" android:text="Waybill Type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner_waybilltype"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left"></Spinner>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Agent ID"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Manifest Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Manifest Date"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Trip Sheet Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Trip Sheet Date"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Vehicle Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="WAYFX"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Waybill Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Number of Articles"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to add a ScrollView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

or

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-scrollview-example/

The only thing is, the ScrollView can have only one component, so you should wrap all your tables inside a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="none">
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"


android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
<TableRow>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_waybilltype"
        android:layout_column="1" android:text="Waybill Type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner_waybilltype"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="left"></Spinner>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Agent ID"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Manifest Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Manifest Date"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Trip Sheet Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Trip Sheet Date"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Vehicle Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="WAYFX"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Waybill Number"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView android:text="Number of Articles"
    android:layout_column="1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:singleLine="true" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</scrollview>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add all the views inside a ScrollView. The catch is that the ScrollView can accomodate only 1 wrapper view. For the scenario this view should be the TableView

ScrollView
    TableLayout